# More than one ejb found with interface of type for binding

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly, ejb-3.0

I have an interface like this:

```
@Local
public interface MyInterface {
}
```

And two classes that implements this interface:

```
@Singleton
public class FirstBean implements MyInterface {
}

@Singleton
public class SecondBean implements MyInterface {
}
```

And another class like below:

```
@Singleton
public class ThirdBean {

    @EJB
    private MyInterface xpto;

}
```

And i am receiving the following error on deploy:

**More than one ejb found with interface of type for binding**

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use qalifier

```
@java.lang.annotation.Documented
@java.lang.annotation.Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE,ElementType.FIELD})
@javax.inject.Qualifier
public @interface First {

}
```

Mark bean using this qualifier

```
@Singleton
@First
public class FirstBean implements MyInterface {
}
```

Then inject it

```
@Singleton
public class ThirdBean {

    @Inject
    @First
    private MyInterface xpto;

}
```